# Kafka consumer offset auto-reset and other parameters

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a KafkaConsumer which needs to subscribe to two topics `topicA` and `topicB`. However I need some parameters be different. E.g. if I need `auto.offset.reset` for `topicA` be `earilest` while for `topicB` it should be `latest`. I see no easy way to do that. One option is to run two consumers, but in this case I need two polling threads for them and hence should handle multi-threading. Is there any simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

Creating two (or more) threads is correct.

Consumers are not thread-safe, and should be isolated and separated from other processes anyway.

You could use higher-level Kafka libraries (e.g. Vert.x / Spring) for simplifying this.

Comment: It just makes live harder. I could have a simple single-threaded app which consumes something from topics, then produces some results to topics. No multithreading headache at all. But because of this limitation I need the extra complexity... More over the multithreading could reduce performance. Any chance?..

Comment: Most production Java applications have several threads. Threads and performace reduction is a myth, IMO, if you are not using all cores of the CPU, then your single threaded app is not performing as much as it could... If you really wanted a "simple app" that "consumes and produces", then use Kafka Streams

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use one consumer, then I think you could set `auto.reset.offset` to `latest` and then move offsets of `topicA` manually (if needed). To do so, between subscription and poll loop you could:

1. Get partitions assigned to the consumer (method [assignment](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#assignment--))
2. Check commited offsets of topic `topicA` by filtering partitions of `topicA` from the previous point (method [committed](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#committed-java.util.Set-)). If the result is `null`, then call [seekToBeginning](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#seekToBeginning-java.util.Collection-) method.

Comment: Huh... The manual assignment is yet another extra complexity...

Comment: Well, I don't think there is an easier option for one consumer subscribed to 2 topics and with different auto reset option. After all, it's quite a rare requirement, isn't it?